# sort array and input it into another array in php

Tags: php, arrays

This is a result of an array when I print it:

```
print_r($frequency);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [A] => 1
    [very] => 1
    [nice] => 2
    [to] => 3
    [tot] => 1
    [text] => 2
    [Something] => 1
    [think] => 1
    [about] => 1
    [if] => 1
    [you're] => 1
    [into] => 1
)
```

I want to order it by numbers and then input words to another array.
I want something like this array:

```
newArray(to,nice,text,a,very,tot,something,think,about,if,your're,into)
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Have a look at the asort() and array_keys() functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
asort($frequency);
```

sorts an array by it's value from low to high and keeps the assosiation.

I don't know about the part with the ne array, as I don't understand what you want to do in that.

Comment: ^ If you don't understand it how can you answer it? Use comments for clarification

Answer (score 0):

```
arsort($frequency);
$newArray = array_keys($frequency);
```